# Error when I return an object by an inline function call into another object in ES6/Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

When trying to return an object containing objects from function/method calls in a React application, I get:

```
Syntax error: this is a reserved word
```

The code causing this error is:

```
const object = {
                this.methodOne(),
                this.methodTwo(),
                this.methodThree()
                };
```

I want to return objects into one object, but the syntax error doesn't seem to recognize that I'm trying call these functions to create the objects like:

```
methodOne(){
    return {foo: "bar"}
}
```

The same issue occurs with a function separate from my class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. If you don't want to declare these with an object key and instead want them to use the key value pair they are returning directly in the object, you have to use the spread operator:

```
const object = {
                ...this.methodOne(),
                ...this.methodTwo(),
                ...this.methodThree()
                    };
```

This ES6 notation tells JavaScript to use the key/value pairs in the object for the objects returned.